# Angular 2 complex interpolation property

Tags: angular

I have a component with this code

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of dataset">
    <td *ngFor="let column of columns">{{row[column.value]}}</td>
</tr>
```

the property of the object is displayed correctly if the `column.value` has a simple value but it does not appear if the value has a complex value such as `property.nestedproperty`.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you plese explain what you're trying to achieve, at ahigher level? Why have such dynamic templates? Where do these column values come from?

Comment: You can create a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue multiple times, the best way to get around this is declare a method in component say getColumnValue() where you calculate and put all the logic.
 In your component class 
..

```
getColumnValue(){
   //logic to get the column value
    return value
}
```

Then bind this method to innerHtml attribute of `<td>`
So instead of

```
 <td *ngFor="let column of columns">{{row[column.value]}}</td>
```

Use

```
<td *ngFor="let column of columns" [innerHtml]="getColumnValue ()"> </td>
```

This is the easiest way to get around, other methods include creating a generic component or directive or child component etc.
But trust me the above is most clear and concise way.